# Is it more natural to say "During my entire visit" or "during my whole visit"?

Tags: style

What's more natural: "during my entire visit" or '"during my whole visit"?

For example:

> I was protected by him **during the entire visit**.

or

> I was protected by him **during the whole visit**.

Comment: About the same. [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=during+my+whole+visit%2Cduring+my+entire+visit&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cduring%20my%20whole%20visit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cduring%20my%20entire%20visit%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cduring%20my%20whole%20visit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cduring%20my%20entire%20visit%3B%2Cc0) bears this out

Comment: Whatever you actually mean here, the sentences sound somewhat awkward. What kind of protection? From what?

Comment: Agree with Lambie, that it sounds somewhat awkward. One reason:  it could be that "the visit" is more common than "my visit" in English.   So, if you swap out "my" with "the" it sounds a little better.

Comment: Can this count as [a](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/94953/whole-vs-entire) [duplicate](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16606/where-to-use-entire-and-where-whole)?

Answer (score 0):

As an adjective, both the words "entire and whole" are synonyms and interchangeable. Although the word "entire" is a bit formal, the use of these words in the sentence stated is natural and common.